# add class active in a complex menu

Tags: javascript, php, menu, nav

I saw many questions like mine but I can't write this JS.
I have a menu like this and I need to put the `class="active"` in the `<li>` tag of the page where the user is. This nav-bar is in a php file that I include in each page of the site. Sorry but after 28h of coding I am fuse!

```
        <div class="componant-section" id="navbars">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-2"><span class="fa fa-bars"></span></button>
                <img class="logo" src="http://<?php echo $base_url ?>/images/logos.png" alt="" width="127">
                </div>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-2">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="http://<?php echo $base_url ?>/home.php">Home</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Clienti <span class="fa-chevron-down fa"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <div class="arrow top"></div>
                            <li><a href="http://<?php echo $base_url ?>/function/agg_cliente.php">Aggiungi nuovo...</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://<?php echo $base_url ?>/lista_clienti.php">Lista</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Fornitori <span class="fa-chevron-down fa"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <div class="arrow top"></div>
                                <li><a href="http://<?php echo $base_url ?>/function/agg_fornitore.php">Aggiungi nuovo...</a></li>
                                <li><a href="http://<?php echo $base_url ?>/lista_fornitori.php">Lista</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="http://<?php echo $base_url ?>/fatture.php">Fatture</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://<?php echo $base_url ?>/ddt.php">DDT</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://<?php echo $base_url ?>/preventivi.php">Preventivi</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://<?php echo $base_url ?>/ndc.php">NDC</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://<?php echo $base_url ?>/listini.php">Listini</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Controllo <span class="fa-chevron-down fa"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <div class="arrow top"></div>
                                <li><a href="http://<?php echo $base_url ?>/check/ck_login.php">Login</a></li>
                                <li><a href="http://<?php echo $base_url ?>/check/ck_causale.php">Causale</a></li>
                                <li><a href="http://<?php echo $base_url ?>/check/ck_mezzo.php">Mezzo Trasporto</a></li>
                                <li><a href="http://<?php echo $base_url ?>/check/ck_iva.php">IVA</a></li>
                                <li><a href="http://<?php echo $base_url ?>/check/ck_imb.php">Imballo</a></li>
                                <li><a href="http://<?php echo $base_url ?>/check/ck_art.php">Articoli</a></li>
                                <li><a href="http://<?php echo $base_url ?>/check/ck_spagg.php">Spese Aggiuntive</a></li>
                                <li><a href="http://<?php echo $base_url ?>/check/ck_pagam.php">Pagamento</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right navbar-icons">
                        <li><a><span class="fa-user fa"></span>
                            <span class="hidden-lg"><?php echo $user; ?></span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://<?php echo $base_url ?>/function/logout.php">
                            <span class="fa-cog fa"></span>
                            <span class="hidden-lg">Logout</span>
                            <span class="navbar-new"></span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
            </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </nav>
    </div>
```

Comment: You want to add `class="active"` to what? The anchor tag `<a href=` or the list item `<li>` ? Can you update your question and be a little more specific please, thank you.

Comment: @NewToJS sorry, in italy it was 2am when I wrote ;p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something a simple as this Javascript solution.

```
window.onload=function(){
var Nav=document.getElementById(window.location.href.split('/').pop().split('.')[0]);
if(Nav){
Nav.setAttribute('class','active');
}}
```

**How does it work?**

Elements you wish to add the class to must have an ID matching the page name

Example

From: `<a href="http://<?php echo $base_url ?>/fatture.php">Fatture</a>`

To: `<a id="fatture" href="http://<?php echo $base_url ?>/fatture.php">Fatture</a>`

The javascript above will strip down the clients location `www.something.com/fatture.php` to `fatture` by splitting the string from `/` creating an array. The name of the file is last in the array so `pop()` is used to select the last item in the array leaving you with `fatture.php` the string is split once again at `.` creating a new array, the first item in that array is then used in the ID selector "fatture".  `document.getElementById('fatture')`

> URL Breakdown

**1)** window.location.href = www.something.com/fatture.php

**2)** .split('/') =>

- array[0] = www.something.com
- array[1] = fatture.php

**3)** .pop() = Last array/array[1] of .split('/') - fatture.php

**4)** .split('.')[0] = fatture

If you have any questions about the source code above please leave a comment below and I will reply as soon as possible.

I hope this helps. Happy coding!

Comment: yes I saw this in other questions but I didn't use because if it put the class active in, for example, `Login` that is under `Controllo`, it put the class in the page but not in the "parent". sorry for my bad english :/

Answer (score 2):

I resolved with

```
<div class="componant-section" id="navbars">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-2"><span class="fa fa-bars"></span></button>
                <img class="logo" src="http://<?php echo $base_url ?>/images/logos.png" alt="" width="127">
                </div>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-2">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li id="home"><a href="http://<?php echo $base_url ?>/home.php">Home</a></li>
                        <li class="agg_cliente lista_clienti dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Clienti <span class="fa-chevron-down fa"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <div class="arrow top"></div>
                            <li id="agg_cliente"><a href="http://<?php echo $base_url ?>/function/agg_cliente.php">Aggiungi nuovo...</a></li>
                            <li id="lista_clienti"><a href="http://<?php echo $base_url ?>/lista_clienti.php">Lista</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="agg_fornitore lista_fornitori dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Fornitori <span class="fa-chevron-down fa"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <div class="arrow top"></div>
                                <li id="agg_fornitore"><a href="http://<?php echo $base_url ?>/function/agg_fornitore.php">Aggiungi nuovo...</a></li>
                                <li id="lista_fornitori"><a href="http://<?php echo $base_url ?>/lista_fornitori.php">Lista</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li id="fatture"><a href="http://<?php echo $base_url ?>/fatture.php">Fatture</a></li>
                        <li id="ddt"><a href="http://<?php echo $base_url ?>/ddt.php">DDT</a></li>
                        <li id="preventivi"><a href="http://<?php echo $base_url ?>/preventivi.php">Preventivi</a></li>
                        <li id="ndc"><a href="http://<?php echo $base_url ?>/ndc.php">NDC</a></li>
                        <li id="listini"><a href="http://<?php echo $base_url ?>/listini.php">Listini</a></li>
                        <li class="ck_login ck_causale ck_mezzo ck_iva ck_imb ck_art ck_spagg ck_pagam dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Controllo <span class="fa-chevron-down fa"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <div class="arrow top"></div>
                                <li id="ck_login"><a href="http://<?php echo $base_url ?>/check/ck_login.php">Login</a></li>
                                <li id="ck_causale"><a href="http://<?php echo $base_url ?>/check/ck_causale.php">Causale</a></li>
                                <li id="ck_mezzo"><a href="http://<?php echo $base_url ?>/check/ck_mezzo.php">Mezzo Trasporto</a></li>
                                <li id="ck_iva"><a href="http://<?php echo $base_url ?>/check/ck_iva.php">IVA</a></li>
                                <li id="ck_imb"><a href="http://<?php echo $base_url ?>/check/ck_imb.php">Imballo</a></li>
                                <li id="ck_art"><a href="http://<?php echo $base_url ?>/check/ck_art.php">Articoli</a></li>
                                <li id="ck_spagg"><a href="http://<?php echo $base_url ?>/check/ck_spagg.php">Spese Aggiuntive</a></li>
                                <li id="ck_pagam"><a href="http://<?php echo $base_url ?>/check/ck_pagam.php">Pagamento</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right navbar-icons">
                        <li><a><span class="fa-user fa"></span>
                            <span class="hidden-lg"><?php echo $user; ?></span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://<?php echo $base_url ?>/function/logout.php">
                            <span class="fa-cog fa"></span>
                            <span class="hidden-lg">Logout</span>
                            <span class="navbar-new"></span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
            </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </nav>
    </div>
```

and javascript

```
window.onload=function(){
var Navid = document.getElementById(window.location.href.split('/').pop().split('.')[0]);

if(Navid){
    Navid.setAttribute('class','active');
    var father = Navid.parentNode,
        grandFather = father.parentNode;
    grandFather.setAttribute('class','active');
}
```

}

Comment: You don't need to repost it as a answer, you only need to mark it :p Just so you know for future :D

Comment: oh ok sorry, I reposted it even for nav modified but ok. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can access the path accessed successfully most of the time in PHP by using the global server request URI variable `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`.

Simply, you need to compare the value of `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to the target of the links in your navigation, and apply a class if it matches. For example:

```
<li><a href="/ddt.php" <?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] === '/ddt.php' ? 'class="active"' : '' ?>>DDT</a></li>
```

As a sidenote, you need not use PHP to generate absolute links for your hrefs in HTML - just use relative paths, e.g. `/listini.php` instead of `http://<?php echo $base_url ?>/listini.php`.

Your life would be much easier if you looked into using a templating language such as [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org), that separates the logic that dictates how a page should be displayed from the actual layout code.

Comment: I used relative paths but in some cases (like page in check dir or in functions dir) server doesn't find anything